# Function to click the List after updated

Tags: database, forms, function, ms-access, addition

As you can see in the Image i select the RoleID´s both by selecting the Name in a dropdown List, now after selecting, i have to click both of the Lists so the Formular gets the RoleID, otherwise the data which is added is 00000 for the Row i didn't click (the List on the right is irrelevant)

So can i make Access to click the List automatically so i don't get data mistakes if i forget to click em ?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5gXX.png)

I tried to Liste8.Enabled = true in a After Update sub.

[there is obviously not much Code, i just used it to Update the Lists after i Changed the Combo Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW3Rd.png)

[the Makros of the Button might be usefull eventhough they dont workout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y81ZW.png)

Comment: Form does not make sense. Two comboboxes are bound to same field and edit same record.

Comment: @June7 there 2 Different RoleID´s one for FoF one for Fund so they´re not Bound to the same, i only need the RoleIDs from the Table FundNamexRoleID and FoFNamexRoleID, so extract them like this

Comment: The comboboxes are bound to same field. When you select combobox item you change value in record. Unless `Ungebunden` means UNBOUND?

Comment: If you need selection in both comboboxes, then have button code verify both have value and notify user if lacking.

Comment: Yes youre right but i dont know the Makros

Comment: Elementary `If Then Else` VBA.

Comment: I mean why should i need an If clause that the Field has a Value is no question access just needs to see it

Comment: Edit your question to show code.

Comment: @June7 yes i did you would make my day if you can solve the Problem

Comment: Code should be posted as formatted text, not image. But there is nothing in your code that attempts to solve issue. Consider something like: `If IsNull(Me.combo1) Or IsNull(Me.combo2) Then MsgBox "Must enter value into both comboboxes." Else 'code to do something End If`.